# C# regular expression match triple quotes """

Tags: c#

I have a text file that contain 3 quotations (""") in various lines in text. It also have 6 blank spaces before that in every line. 
I have tried doing @"\s{6}\"{3}"; and various cases, but it seems like c# doesn't like when it sees 3 quotations mark together. What I'm trying to do is to find that and add a new line after.

This is what i have tried:

```
 string pattern4 = @"\s{6}"{3}";

 var match4 = Regex.Match(body, pattern4, RegexOptions.Multiline);
 while (match4.Success)
 {
    string index = """;
    output.Insert(index, "\r\n");
 }
```

**Sample Input**:

```
  """Step:    33    And I enter 

  Step:    34    And I set the
```

**Desired Output:**

```
  """

  Step:    33    And I enter    

  Step:    34    And I set THE
```

Comment: `string index = """;`  That is invalid syntax.  Your string ends with the second quote.  If you want a string that contains a single quote character, then use `"\""` instead (escape the quote).

Comment: Thanks is that the same with the pattern?

Comment: I'm not real sure how to use regex very well.  I always use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) when creating regular expressions.  But yes, that will end the string in the regular expression pattern too.

Comment: Can we see a sample input and your desired output?

Comment: This also my first time doing regular expression, and tripple quote seem special

Comment: @FirstStep is that clear, i want to add a new line after the 3 quote and the step 33 can be on a new line

Answer (score 0):

To escape a quote inside a verbatim string (starts with @) use double quotes. Also there is a Regex.Replace method that you could use like this:

```
string input = @"      """"""Step:    33    And I enter 

Step:    34    And I set the  ";

string pattern = @"\s{6}""{3}";
string replacement = "\"\"\"\r\n";

string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Comment: can you explain why you don't use @ on the replacement? And what if i want to add 6 \s on the replacement, how would i do that?

Comment: I didn't use @ on the replacement because it would have been more difficult to express the string content desired in this case. The @ makes it a verbatim string which means everything inside the double quotes is taken as-is, except double quotes - those have to be escaped. Notice that means that you can't express a line break with \r\n - you would actually have to put the closing quote on the next line to get that. And the three quotes in a verbatim string would look like @"""""""". To put 6 \s (spaces) in the replacement just type 6 spaces.